Why is a monochromatic wave temporally coherent for all time delays $\tau$?
I've been learning about coherence of waves and the Wikipedia page on says a monochromatic electromagnetic plane wave is coherent because:

A wave containing only a single frequency (monochromatic) is perfectly correlated with itself at all time delays

I don't fully understand why this is the case for all time delays. For instance if I delay by $1/4$ of the period of the wave then that will turn a cosine wave into a sine wave and so if I were to plot values of the intensities of these two waves on an x-y axes across a set of positions (or even time values) they would form a circle, not a straight line (since the points are related by sin/cos relations on the x and y axes). These points therefore don't have a correlation of $\pm 1$ and so don't represent perfect correlation, which according to the definition given in the article suggests the two waves aren't coherent.
Where's my reasoning going wrong here?

Wouldn't the cosine and sine waves maintain their relationship for all times, hence be correlated?

Having a relation isn't the same as being correlated. For instance $y(x) = |x|$ is a fixed relationship between $y$ and $x$ valid for all $x$ but $x$ and $y$ are uncorrelated here. The definition of coherence given on the wikipedia page is a correlation formula.

According to the Wiener-Khintchine theorem, the degree of temporal coherence of a light wave is proportional to the Fourier transform of the wave's spectrum. Mathematically:
$$\mu(\tau)\propto FT(I(\omega))$$
Where:

$\mu$ is the degree of temporal coherence
$\tau=t_2-t_1$ is the interval in which we evaluate the temporal coherence of the wave
$I(\omega)$ is the intensity of the wave as a function of its spectrum

In a monocrhomatic wave, we only have one frequency, and therefore its Fourier Transform yields a Dirac delta (in practice, a null value everywhere except for one point). Therefore, the degree of coherence will be "proportional to zero" (i.e: it will be zero) regardless of the $\tau$ we choose.
Conclusion: a monocrhomatic wave is coherent for arbitrarily high times

The Wikipedia reference you give, in the chapter [Temporal coherence], does not actually give a mathematical definition of how this "temporal coherence" is supposed to be defined!
If we take it for granted that the definition is just the autocorrelation then you are right.
The claim that "a wave containing only a single frequency (monochromatic) is perfectly correlated with itself at all time delays" is then clearly wrong, especially since Fig. 1, which is a sine wave, is mentioned as an example. And for a sine wave we know that the autocorrelation function is a cosine, because for the autocorrelation function Wikipedia actually does have a [mathematical definition], although that definition does not handle the normalization correctly. That could be solved with:
$$
 R_{ff}(\tau) =\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{-T}^{T}  dt\ f(t+\tau)\, f^*(t)}
                         {\int_{-T}^{T}  dt\ |f(t)|^2}
$$
or we just could directly use the [definition for periodic signals].
We will then find that, if $f(t)=\sin at$, the autocorrelation $R_{ff}(\tau)=\cos at$. And as you explain in the question, at 1/4th period you find $R_{ff}\big(\pi/(2a)\big)=0$. We really cannot call that "perfectly correlated".
The same conclusion holds if $f(t)=\cos at$. But if you have a complex wave: $f(t)=e^{\large iat}$, then the autocorrelation is: $R_{ff}(\tau)=e^{\large ia\tau}$ so in that case the "perfectly correlated at all time delays" could be accepted, if we consider any correlation with absolute value $1$ a perfect correlation.
As for the other answer [#816000], using the [Wiener-Khintchine theorem], that would be fine for the exponential wave with frequency $\omega$, but not for the sine wave because there that claim "we only have one frequency" is not true. A sine wave has a power spectral density with two delta-functions at two frequencies, $-\omega$ and $\omega$. So the Wiener-Khintchine theorem will then correctly give us the same cosine again as result for the autocorrelation.

I thought monocrhomatic waves had, by definition, only one frequency, and that we could use imaginary exponentials and sines /cosines interchangeably. Why isn't this the case? Please let me know so I can edit / delete my answer, I wouldn't like to be spreading misconceptions. Thanks!

@Lagrangiano All monochromatic light has sine wave behavior for the field components (even circularly polarized light), and I would not like to exclude light from a definition of monochromatic!
And the use of exponentials is sometimes just for taking the real part, and sometimes they are the actual solution (like electron waves). You have to know what they mean when you use them. They cannot change the fact that the autocorrelation of a sine is a cosine. So if you describe light with complex exponentials then you first have to take the real part and then compute the autocorrelation.

Thanks for the answer. I thought that the wave represented by $f(t) = \cos(at)$ and the wave represented by $f(t) = e^{iat}$ were the exact same thing, the latter just had a complex part tackled on to create a phasor which makes the mathematics simpler. Are they different waves and if so what physical significance does the imaginary part of $e^{iat}$ have on the wave behaviour?
